# FFMpeg - Combine multiple filter_complex and overlay functions

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having trouble combining these 3 passes in ffmpeg into a single process.

Is this even possible?

Pass 1

```
ffmpeg -y -i C:\Users\MJ\Downloads\20151211_pmoney_pmpod.mp3 -loop 1 -i C:\Users\MJ\Documents\pm1080.png  -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:270[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest C:\Users\MJ\Documents\20151211_pmoney_pmpod4.mp4
```

Pass 2

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\MJ\Documents\20151211_pmoney_pmpod4.mp4" -vf drawtext="fontsize=50:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf:text=Planet Money Podcast on NPR - A/B Split Testing:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=200" -acodec copy "C:\Users\MJ\Documents\20151211_pmoney_pmpod-overlay-text.mp4"
```

Pass 3

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\MJ\Documents\20151211_pmoney_pmpod-overlay-text.mp4" -i C:\Users\MJ\Downloads\6.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" C:\Users\MJ\Documents\20151211_pmoney_pmpod-overlay-text1.mp4"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Join filters with a comma and filterchains with a semicolon:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i image1.png -i image2.png -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line[fg]; \
 [1:v][fg]overlay=0:270,drawtext=fontsize=50:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf:text='Planet Money Podcast on NPR - A/B Split Testing':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=200[bg]; \
 [bg][2:v]overlay=10:10,format=yuv420p[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: That looks great, I was def using the comma and semicolon wrong. But when I run it I get the error: No such filter '\'

Comment: @MikeJohnson I'm not a Windows user so I don't know how it deals with line breaks. You can re-format the command so it's all on one line and it will probably work.