# How would I create a radially offset mosaic of rtsp streams that transitions to a logo

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

I'm new to stack overflow, but I've been researching how to do this for a couple weeks to no avail. I'm hoping perhaps one of you has some knowledge I haven't seen online yet.

Here is a [crude illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcqNB.jpg) of what I hope to accomplish. I have a video wall of eight monitors - four each of two different sizes. The way it's set up now, all eight monitors are treated together as one big monitor displaying an oddly shaped cutout of a desktop.

Eventually I need each individual monitor to display a separate RTSP stream for about thirty seconds, then have the *entire* display - all eight monitors in conjunction - to fade out into a large logo.

My problem right now is that I don't know of a way to mask an rtsp stream so it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWWJ4.jpg) rather than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAHx4.jpg), let alone how to arrange them into a weirdly spaced, oddly angled, multiple aspect-ratio mosaic like in the original illustration.

Thank you all for your time. I'm just an intern here without insane technical knowhow, but I'll try to clarify as much as I can.

-J

Comment: Does this entail any programming?

Comment: Not exactly, most likely some command line stuff for VLC / ffmpeg, but I'm not sure. I'm open to any way I can do this, coding or otherwise, I just need to know what that way is now.

Comment: How are you feeding the monitors at present  - 8 ffmpeg processes?

Comment: It’s a Planar brand video wall. Right now, it’s calibrated so the monitors all together are like one big oddly-shaped window looking at a single Desktop. There is no way I know of to interact with one monitor individually without disturbing the others.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `-filter-complex` is one of the ffmpeg CLI flags that you need. You can find many examples online, but here are a few links of interest:

Here's an ffmpeg wiki on creating a mosaic https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos

[FFMpeg - Combine multiple filter_complex and overlay functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683879/ffmpeg-combine-multiple-filter-complex-and-overlay-functions)

That should get you started, but you will probably need to add customization depending on frame size and formats.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this it seems is a good start, I appreciate it.